# Odoo 12 Report External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid

Tags: python, report, odoo, odoo-12

Hi what i trying to do is create report in odoo 12, here is what i do :

first i create toxicwork_invoice/reports/soreport.xml, and the code looked like this :

```
<odoo>
    <report
        id="so_invoices"
        model="salesorder.salesorder"
        string="Invoices"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="salesorder.report_invoice"
        file="salesorder.report_invoice"
    />
</odoo>
```

and then i create toxicwork_invoice/reports/invoice_card.xml, here is the code :

```
<odoo>

    <template id="report_invoice_cards">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                <h2>Faktur</h2>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>

    <template id="report_invoice">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                <t t-call="report_invoice_cards"/>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

but it give me an error like this

> ```
> raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid) ValueError: External ID not found in the system: salesorder.report_invoice
> ```

What i missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please give the below code;

```
<odoo>
<report
    id="so_invoices"
    model="salesorder.salesorder"
    string="Invoices"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="toxicwork_invoice.report_invoice"
    file="toxicwork_invoice.report_invoice"
/>
</odoo>
```

```
<template id="report_invoice_cards">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <h2>Faktur</h2>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="report_invoice">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="toxicwork_invoice.report_invoice_cards"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```